# Mapbox style zoom over 22

Tags: styles, zooming, mapbox

I know that with custom tilesets it is possible to zoom over 22 (i have several tilesets configured to be zoomed at 22 and more, working perfectly).

But i can't seem to figure out where i can have one of mapbox's styles zoomables over the magic 22 mark.

I have tried with tippecanoe but styles are not tilesets, therefore not doable with what you can download over mapbox studio styles.

Anyone firgured out how to do it ?

Regards,
Alex